# My kitten licks and nips my nose when he's snuggling with me.

Tags: cats, behavior, biting

We rescued Reggie at 3 mths old.  Since I work from home, he is always near me and prefers me over my husband.  We have a bedtime routine which involves me cuddling and kissing his cheek.  He will cuddle close and lick the end of my nose.  Pretty cute, right?  Yeah.  The licks are always followed by him nipping me with his sharp little front teeth.  He's not aggressive by any means, but whyyyyyyyyy bite?
If anyone has any insight on this, I'd love to hear.

Comment: Is it bite, or grab? Probably the latter, and probably play. You can break the habit by breaking the whole pattern -- if he nips, make an ouch noise and immediately stop playing with him. If you permit the behavior, it's permitted....

Answer (score 1):

Licking and soft nipping are signs of affection among cats, so he isn't doing anything wrong per se. If it does hurt you, then make a small 'ouch' noise like lizryan suggested and stop the interaction. If it doesn't, just let him, he likes you :)

As an aside, please do consider getting him a feline playmate of the same age, gender, rough character and activity level. Cats are social creatures, they suffer in various ways when kept alone. 'Even' ferals form social groups if there are sufficient resources to sustain that.

http://katzen-verstehen.at/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/social-organization-of-the-cat.pdf

Comment: Even if it doesn't hurt now, it will probably hurt when Reggie gets older and bigger, so I recommend you discourage the nipping now. Nip that nipping in the bud!

Answer (score -1):

The biting might be a result of over-stimulation. Try to play with your cat 10-15 minutes before bedtime. Playing before will calm him down a bit. This will result in a much happier and relaxed cat who will be less likely to bite. Since when petting a cat's full body, they can get overstimulated which may result in a "love bite." To prevent this I wear my cat out a bit and make sure she's gotten her energy out before night time cuddles. Hope that clarifies my first answer a bit. Good luck with your cat!